# Selectable UITableViewCells inside of a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've been trying to programmatically create a `UITableView` inside of a `UIScrollView` and I'm having some trouble. Basically I want to have the cells to register as "checked" when they are tapped on. I don't need the `UITableView` itself to scroll because the `UIScrollView` will be large enough that this isn't necessary, but I still need the `UIScrollView` to be able to scroll when the user drags  over the `UITableView`. I'm just overall confused about how gesture recognition works with regard to this project. I can't get the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to be called, although I can get the `didHighlightRowAt` method to work. I saw a suggestion to add a `UIScrollView` onto each cell, but this didn't seem to help. Any guidance is appreciated as I'm unsure how exactly to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: `UITableView` is build on top of `UIScrollView` (it's parent class is `UIScrollView`). So you basically tries to put scroll into scroll. Maybe correct approach would be to describe result you are trying to achieve and ask 'how'.

Comment: As I said above, I have a table inside of a scrollview. I want the user to be able to select the table cells by tapping on them. This tap will then change a uiimage on the cell from an empty box to a checked box

Comment: @Ross Harding I still can't see the use of the scrollview. Please help me understand why you need it.

Comment: @NgugiNdung'u the view has various components: a label, a textview, a stepper, and a uitableview at the bottom. All of the content cannot fit into the view without the uiscrollview

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should be using custom `UIButton`s rather than `UITableViewCell`s to allow for selectable content within your `UIScrollView`.